# Does Java make classes Serializable automatically if used in a Serializable interface?

Tags: java, serialization

Let's say I have a Serializable interface as follows

```java
public interface SomeInterface extends Serializable {

     public SomeClass getSomething(String someParameter);

}
```

Will `SomeClass` be Serializable automatically?
To our surprise, our RMI application runs fine even when `SomeClass` does not implement Serializable.

Why is this?

Comment: Only class which are marked Serializable (or sub-class) are Serializable. Most likely `SomeClass` extends or implements something Serializable or Externalizable.

Comment: Or what is being returned is a serializable derived class of `SomeClass`, or null.

Comment: Interfaces are implemented, classes are extended.
Serializable is a class that uses reflection to serialize any subclass.
Note that this is usually very inefficient for complex subclasses - it serializes everything. Use protobuf or externalizable for more efficient marshaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will `SomeClass` be `Serializable` automatically? To our surprise, our RMI application runs fine even when `SomeClass` does not implement `Serializable`.

No.

Serialization is about serializing the (non-transient) state of an object.  The presence of a `getSomething` in the signature of some method doesn't *require* the state of your instance of a `SomeInterface` to include a `SomeClass` instance.

The method could be implemented to return a newly created `SomeClass`, the value of a `transient` field, the result of calling a `static` method on some other class, or .... `null`.

Answer (score 0):

No, Any class just referenced within a class that is serializable is not serializable by default.

Ideally `java` should throw [`NotSerializableException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html), but since you are not getting the exception means, `SomeClass` `extends Serializable` by it's parent hierarchy somewhere.

Comment: Or it was null, or an instance of a serializable derived class.

Answer (score -1):

No, `SomeClass` will not be `Serializable` just because this interface extends `Serializable`.

`Serializable` applies to the state of the object, there isn't anything here to imply that SomeClass is part of the state of SomeInterface.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Are you sue that when `SomeClass` is being Deserialized it doesn't extend a class that implements `Serializable`?

Comment: `Serializable` applies primarily to the definition of the class. If `SomeClass` isn't `Serializable` it will never be *serialized*, so it is idle to ask questions about what happens during *de*-serialization

Answer (score -1):

Suppose an implementation of `SomeInterface` just does something similar to

```
public class SomeInterfaceImpl implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    public SomeClass getSomething(String someParameter) {
        return new SomeClass(someParameter);
    }
}
```

Why should your program fail on serializing objects of `SomeInterfaceImpl` when objects of `SomeClass` are just created *on the fly*?

## Minimal Example

## Main.java

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                final ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream)) {
            final SomeInterfaceImpl someInterfaceImpl = new SomeInterfaceImpl();
            final SomeClass something1 = someInterfaceImpl.getSomething("Test");
            out.writeObject(someInterfaceImpl);

            try (final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
                    final ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
                final SomeInterface someInterface = (SomeInterface) in.readObject();
                final SomeClass something2 = someInterface.getSomething("Test");

                final String someParameter1 = something1.getSomeParameter();
                System.out.println(someParameter1);

                final String someParameter2 = something2.getSomeParameter();
                System.out.println(someParameter2);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this out? In doubt, I have added a minimal example serializing and deserializing successfully.